# How can I download an image from this web page? [with LINK]

Tags: html, css, image

Hello I am new to the forum and a beginner in terms of Web Design. I am currently working on a project for my College Graphic Design class and I am trying to figure out how to download the high quality image from this page:
https://digital.lib.uh.edu/collection/pixel/item/111

It shows that the image is available on the page at 10714x14240px which is the size I need. The page allows you to zoom in on the image as well. I would like to be able to download the high resolution version if possible.
I'd greatly appreciate anyone who could assist with this issue.
Thank You

I checked under the "Application" section of Google Chrome Web Developer tool to see if I could download the image but it only shows the image as a smaller size, or it shows the large image broken up into smaller jpeg sections.

Comment: Seems like you need to ask the enlarged version of the image, don't you think so? Anyway, if the browser has it, of course you can download the whole enlarged pieces and combine them later. Check the legal issue first. GL

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I requested the Hi-Res Version from them and they happily provided it, but it wasn't the full size. The one they provided me with was just slightly over 1000px at 72ppi

Comment: If they approve using the full scale image, and cannot supply. You can easily get the image chunks by listening the chrome developer tools "network" tab (while you using the enlarge button). Download the whole chunks and combine them later with your preferred image editor software.